# Duda de hilos en Java

Tags: java, hilos

Estoy probando hilos en Java y me he quedado en una parte en la cual no se como seguir. El problema es el siguiente:

Tengo 3 hilos en ejecución y me gustaría saber como puedo detener el segundo hilo solo si el primer hilo está suspendido. La parte de suspender el primer hilo me funciona (al llegar al 15 el primer hilo se detiene), pero no consigo hacer que se me detenga el segundo. He visto por algunos sitios que con el método isAlive se hace, pero no se como aplicarlo.

Adjunto lo que tengo del código.

```
public class Hilos extends Thread {

public Hilos(String nombre) {
    super(nombre);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
        System.out.println("" + getName() + " paso " + i);

        if ((i == 15) && (getName().equals("Hilo 1"))) {
            System.out.println("" + getName() + " está suspendido.");
            suspend();

        }

        System.out.println("Acaba " + getName());
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hilos h1 = new Hilos("Hilo 1");
    Hilos h2 = new Hilos("Hilo 2");
    Hilos h3 = new Hilos("Hilo 3");

    h1.start();
    h2.start();
    h3.start();
}
}
```

Comment: Ahora si que compila, el que me ha editado la pregunta ha quitado un corchete y se ha hecho un lio el código.
Y sobre lo de detener el "Hilo 2", quiero que se detenga pero sólo si el "Hilo 1" está suspendido.

Answer (score 2):

Quizás lo más lógico sería pausar el Hilo2 desde el Hilo1 antes de hacer el suspend(), pero no siempre la solción más lógica es la más funcional.

Dale vueltas a este código, en el que se usa un coordinator para el entendimiento entre los dos hilos:

```
final Thread subject1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

  public void run() {
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
      Thread.yield();
    }
    System.out.println("subject 1 stopped!");
  }
});

final Thread subject2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

  public void run() {
    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
      Thread.yield();
    }
    System.out.println("subject 2 stopped!");
  }
});

final Thread coordinator = new Thread(new Runnable() {

  public void run() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
    System.out.println("coordinator stopping!");
    subject1.interrupt();
    subject2.interrupt();
  }
});

subject1.start();
subject2.start();
coordinator.start();
```

Comment: Sigo sin saber como hacerlo con el método isAlive(), que es con lo que lo quiero hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Los métodos *stop()*, *suspend()* y *resume()* son marcados *@Deprecated* y no es recomendable de seguir usandolos.

Se recomienda de simplemente salir del método *run()* del hilo por ejemplo con un return, así el hilo termina naturalmente.